# Iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension (Python 3 `*` operator)

Tags: python, syntax, iterator, set, iterable-unpacking

I have a `pd.Series` that contains `str` representations of `sets`.  I want to use `iterable unpacking` to empty all of these lists into a single container (intuitively, the syntax makes perfect sense).  I'm running `3.5.2` right now.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval # builtin module
Se = pd.Series(["{'a','b','c'}", "{'d','e','f'}","{'g'}"])
[literal_eval(x) for x in Se]
# [{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}, {'g'}]
[*literal_eval(x) for x in Se]
#   File "<ipython-input-27-692f886a59ef>", line 4
#     [*literal_eval(x) for x in Se]
#     ^
# SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
```

I want to end up w/ a `set` that is: `{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'}` (obviously this isn't my real data but it's analogous).  None of the `sets` are nested or anything.

**Is there a way that is less verbose than (below) that uses the `*` unpacking operator?**

```
set_concat = set()
for x in Se:
    for y in literal_eval(x):
        set_concat.update(y)
set_concat
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}
```

Comment: Duplicate for sure.  Thanks for that; I wasn't sure how to exactly search for this so I didn't find it.

Comment: `S.union(*Se.map(lambda x:literal_eval(x)))` where `S = set()` did the trick

Comment: It would be better to use `S.union(*Se.map(literal_eval))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is redundant to use `lambda x`?

Comment: @O.rka looks pretty redundant to me. It will also slow down what you are doing for sure. Although `Series.map` is pretty slow as it is, since it is basically a python for-loop with cruft.

Comment: I've only seen it used w/ `lambda` before but this will make things even quicker!  Thanks for tip.  Going to start using it this way now.