# python generator example with star expression

Tags: python-3.x

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), the definition of the generator expression reads

```
generator_expression ::=  "(" expression comp_for ")"
```

whereas in the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/grammar.html) it is hidden and reads

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' | .......
testlist_comp: (test|star_expr) ( comp_for | (',' (test|star_expr))* [','] )
```

According to the grammar, "(" "*" expression comp_for ")" is a valid generator expression but is is not detailed in the documentation. Can someone point me to a concrete example for this kind of generator with a star.

Assuming `myList = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))`, consider for example `(*x for x in myList)`

1. `myList` is an atom
2. `for x in myList` matches comp_for according to

   comp_for: 'for' exprlist 'in' or_test
3. `*x` matches `star_expr` thus `test|star_expr`
4. `*x for x in myList` matches `testlist_comp`
5. finally `(*x for x in myList)` is a valid atom because it matches `'(' testlist_comp ')'`

The python interpreter gives
SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251729/unpacking-generalizations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190547/iterable-unpacking-cannot-be-used-in-comprehension-python-3-operator

Comment: Do you mean something like `[*x for x in ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))]`?  because i get "SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension" when I try that.  Where are you getting that star?

Comment: `(*x,)` works, but has nothing directly to do with your question :)

Answer (score 1):

What's legal syntax in Python is not exactly the same as what's described by the grammar. The various calls to `ast_error` in ast.c are examples of cases that are allowed by the grammar but are not valid. "positional argument follows keyword argument" is one of the most familiar: there's nothing in the grammar that disallows

```
def foo(what=None, how):
    pass
```

but this does raise a SyntaxError (see [this line in ast.c in the cpython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/383b32fe108ea627699cc9c644fba5f8bae95d73/Python/ast.c#L2773)).